# Call a class when you click a button flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add call a class when i press a button that will appear on the home page.

You can check this picture here: https://gyazo.com/f9cc3e2c1f48e9efeb7b1d1c9b0b988e?token=2a469e052082aa1b5cddca06b8514a84

As you can see, you have the add device button and once you click it it should spawn the home care kit which is a class. So they need to appear above the button.

Here is the button

```
      child: RaisedButton(
  
  elevation: 0,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
  onPressed: () {print('asd');},
  color: Colors.transparent,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: Text('Add Device', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
  
),
```

Ant the class is in another folder with the name 'HomeCareKit()'

Do you have any tips how i can make this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Navigator.push()`,

Example:

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeCareKit()));
},
```

Comment: i get some errors when adding this line: https://gyazo.com/f3c2f65fda407fb61d6a65edc614162e

Comment: the `onPressed()` method is of your button, also can you show your code?

Comment: this is the onpress: https://gyazo.com/57f5f9bba32abd6cf4ba88aa3ffddbd8

Comment: this is how the HomeCareKit class starts: https://gyazo.com/a0742af06aa76bca78d7d8c4e840e3a7

Comment: It works but i get this error https://gyazo.com/63af20e1e14ac97d34cf801ebed561cb

if i add another page, it works redirecting to the page but if i add the class i get that error.

Comment: wrap your existing `Container` widget inside a `Scaffold` in the HomeCareKit,
eg.: `return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: YourContainer())`

Comment: if i wrap it in scaffold, it fits in the whole screen like this: https://gyazo.com/8afe88ac2e089eefdf461df961462b0a

Comment: well thats a different issue altogether, i suggest you look at the Flutter tutorials on how to align, resize widgets. If the above answer has fixed your asked Que. please accept it. :)

Comment: The thing is that i want it to appear on the same page as the button, so you can add as many as you want. Not a separate page

Comment: You mean to show/hide the HomeCareKit widget on button click?
If thats the case, use `StatefulWidget` & wrap your `Container` inside a `Visibility` widget, change states on button click.

Comment: my idea was something like this: https://medium.com/@anilpandey071999/dynamically-adding-widgets-on-buttons-on-pressed-function-in-flutter-4d9f139744c7

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to a different screen can use flutter default Navigator

eg

```
   onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => AdsDetailes(
              ads: ads,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
```

Comment: The i want is, when you press the button, i want it to add a widget on the current screen, not open a new page.

Comment: Then store the widgets in a list and when you click the button add a new widget to the list.